# How to setup Stack segment in protected mode?

Tags: assembly, x86, operating-system, nasm, protected-mode

This problem is that I defined one Data and Stack segment in x86 protected mode with selector under GDT. When jmp to protected mode, It seems I can access the data section but crash when push eax. See following Code:

```
%include "../inc/descriptor.asm"
%include "../inc/define.asm"

org     7c00h
        jmp  begin
; -----------------------------------------------------------------------
; Const variable
STACK_BASE  EQU  1000000h       ; 16M
DATA_BASE   EQU  2000000h       ; 32M
STACK_SIZE  EQU     8000h       ; 32K
STACK_LIMIT EQU  1008000h       ; 16M + 32K
DATA_SIZE   EQU   100000h       ;  1M

; GDT and LDT
; Descriptor                  base               limit        property
[SECTION .gdt]
GDT:        Descriptor           0,                  0,              0
LDT_CODE32: Descriptor           0, SEG_CODE32_LEN - 1,   DA_C + DA_32
LDT_VIDEO:  Descriptor     0B8000h,             0ffffh,         DA_DRW
LDT_STACK:  Descriptor  STACK_BASE,     STACK_SIZE - 1, DA_DRWA + DA_B
LDT_DATA:   Descriptor   DATA_BASE,      DATA_SIZE - 1,         DA_DRW

GDTLEN EQU $ - GDT
GDTPTR DW  GDTLEN - 1
       DD  0

; Selectors
SLT_CODE32 EQU LDT_CODE32 - GDT
SLT_VIDEO  EQU LDT_VIDEO - GDT
SLT_STACK  EQU LDT_STACK - GDT
SLT_DATA   EQU LDT_DATA - GDT
; -----------------------------------------------------------------------


; Real mode code
[SECTION .s16]
[BITS 16]
begin:
         mov     ax, cs
         mov     ds, ax

         ; init 32 bits code section descriptor
         xor     eax, eax
         mov     ax, cs
         shl     eax, 4
         add     eax, code32
         mov     word [LDT_CODE32 + 2], ax
         shr     eax, 16
         mov     byte [LDT_CODE32 + 4], al
         mov     byte [LDT_CODE32 + 7], ah

         ; prepare for loading gdtr
         xor     eax, eax
         mov     ax, ds
         shl     eax, 4
         add     eax, GDT
         mov     dword [GDTPTR + 2], eax

         lgdt    [GDTPTR]

         cli

         in      al, 92h
         or      al, 10b
         out     92h, al

         mov     eax, cr0
         or      eax, 1
         mov     cr0, eax


         jmp     dword SLT_CODE32:0

; protected mode code
[SECTION .s32]
[BITS 32]
code32:
         mov     ax, SLT_VIDEO
         mov     gs, ax

         mov     ax, SLT_STACK
         mov     ss, ax
         mov     esp, STACK_LIMIT - 16
         mov     ax, SLT_DATA
         mov     ds, ax
         mov     eax, 012345678h
         xor     edx, edx
         mov     [edx], eax
         mov     edx, [edx]
         push    eax ;             **<= crashed here.**

         ; ---------------------------------
         ; PREPARE DEBUG CHAR
         mov     ax, SLT_VIDEO
         mov     gs, ax
         mov     bh, 0ch
         mov     bl, 'B'
         mov     esi, (80 * 1 + 1) * 2
         mov     [gs:esi], bx
         jmp     $
         ; ; END OF PREPARE DEBUG CHAR
         ; ---------------------------------
         push    eax

         pop     ebx
         mov     eax, DATA_BASE
         mov     dword [eax], ebx

         mov     edi, 0
         mov     esi, (80 * 1 + 1) * 2
         call    PRINT_DWORD
         jmp     $

         ; ---------------------------------
         ; ; PREPARE DEBUG CHAR
         ; mov     ax, SLT_VIDEO
         ; mov     gs, ax
         ; mov     bh, 0ch
         ; mov     bl, 'B'
         ; mov     esi, (80 * 1 + 1) * 2
         ; mov     [gs:esi], bx
         ; jmp     $
         ; ; END OF PREPARE DEBUG CHAR
         ; ---------------------------------

SEG_CODE32_LEN EQU $ - code32
times    290 - ($ - $$) db 0
dw       0xaa55
; command reference:
;     nasm protected_mode.asm -o pm.bin
;     dd if=pm.bin of=pm.img bs=512 count=1
```

Descriptor.asm:

```
;
; Descriptor base, limit, attr
;     base:  dd
;     limit: dd low 20 bits available
;     attr:  dw low nibble of higher byte always 0
;
%macro Descriptor 3
       dw    %2 & 0FFFFh
       dw    %1 & 0FFFFh
       db    (%1 >> 16) & 0FFh
       dw    ((%2 >> 8) & 0F00h) | (%3 & 0F0FFh)
       db    (%1 >> 24) & 0FFh
%endmacro
;
```

Define.asm:

```
;
DA_32         EQU 4000h
DA_DRW        EQU   92h
DA_DRWA       EQU   93h
DA_C          EQU   98h
DA_B          EQU DA_32
DA_ELEMENT_4K EQU 8000h
;

; Paging Entry Attribute
PG_P    EQU    1
PG_RW_W EQU    2
PG_US_U EQU    4
```

Comment: Instead of defining separate data, stack and video segments, you can simplify things by creating only one data segment that refers to all of memory like your code segment does.

Comment: Yes, I just want to have a try on standalone stack segment selector. For convention, it should be done as you said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you set the segment base to `STACK_BASE` you must not add that into the stack pointer. As such, `mov esp, STACK_LIMIT - 16` should be `mov esp, STACK_SIZE - 16`.

PS: you never set up `cs`, so your code might break on systems where it's not zero.

Comment: Thanks, but the stack esp should be pointer to highest address of segment for downwards grows. And another question about cs, how can I get the cs in protected mode ?

Comment: Yes, `esp` will be the highest **offset** relative to the segment base, which is the `STACK_BASE` already set in the GDT. I don't understand your question about `cs`.

Comment: you said in that code I never set up cs register. It seems I have no idea about this, and could you plz help to explain about this ? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use a far jump to your entry point, instead of `jmp begin` do `jmp 0:begin`.

Comment: I still have question about set up esp of this segment. The segment start at 16M, and ends 16M + 32K. If set esp to STACK_BASE, It is a full stack ? Or you mean STACK_BASE is the highest address of Stack segment, and the range should be from 16M - 32K to 16M? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I Got it, the property of GDT should specific the downwards grow, I used incorrect attribute of that segment, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I root caused why that push instruction will result in crash. Thanks Jester for help. And I write it here for someone else may missing comments.

When defined one stack segment, the attribute of GDT always should be set as downwards grows with TYPE 6/7. And the segment base STACK_BASE defines the highest 
address of that segment with STACK_SIZE. So the range should be from STACK_BASE - STACK_SIZE to STACK_BASE.

Then set the esp with STACK_BASE, and you can use stack now.
Thanks all for your help. :)